# I can't figure out the brand of this fork

Tags: identify-this-bike, fork, badge

I recently bought this used fork for a project and I can't figure out what brand it is, I looked for and compared every brand that starts with the letter 'C' but I couldn't find anything with this exact logo. The closest one i found is Columbus which had a similar font, but nothing more. Also there's nothing written on the dropouts (like the usual "brev. campagnolo"). I appreciate every suggestion. Thank you in advance!

Edit: While I was taking the other pictures, I noticed some details that may be useful:

1. It came with an incomplete shimano headset (there's no 'cover' for the top bearing), I assume it's a shimano 105 because it also came with a shimano 105 front brake and as for a small research they look really similar.
2. It looks like the hole for the brake has been enlarged (on both sides) or even added by someone after the fork was made.

While I'm at it i'll also add a picture of the brake so that you can have all the details.

[image: Fork logo]
[image: Dropouts]
[image: Fork's front]
[image: Inside of the fork]
[image: Side]
[image: Headset]
[image: Brake front]
[image: Brake back]

Comment: It would be nice to know what the brand is, but if the fork appears to be good quality, the right size, and undamaged then it will suit your need no-matter who made it.   TBH it looks quite svelt, like a dainty 80's road fork in steel.   A couple more photos showing the whole thing could be useful too.

Comment: The fork is in really good conditions and the brand doesn't really matter for my project: the search for the brand started as pure curiosity and when I couldn't find anything I got more and more interested. I'll add other photos right away, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer!

I was looking for some bike parts for the project and a really nice bike caught my attention, it had the name "COPPI" so my brain clicked cause of the initial (which was the same stamped on my fork). After a bit of research i found a Coppi's bike with a fork that had the same exact logo on it.

So yeah! The fork's brand is COPPI!

The brand of the bike i found is actually "Fausto Coppi", and the frame has "La Fausto Coppi" stamped on it (it means "The Fausto Coppi" in Italian); so I guess that my new objective is to get a Fausto Coppi frame (I love how it looks) and make a bike faithful to the original (given the average price I will probably settle for a used Coppi frame) with some modifications of course. Once I finish it, I'll be sure to post the end result.

This was a fun journey, thank you for all the help!

I'll attach a picture of the bike I was talking about :)

[image]

Comment: Wow, congratulations for your happy ending! It's a fine piece of (p)art and in this case it absolutely paid off to know the make of it, unlike many other requests here. Please just make sure to put a Campagnolo gruppo on the full build so that it is the real thing. :)

Answer (score 1):

That's a nice fork! Based on the curve of the tines, its no older than the mid 1980s and could date from the early `90s.

The crown is clearly a cast part because we can see a moulding-part line.

The brake calipers are very handy - thanks for including them.  They date from 1985-1989, as listed at Velobase.  Your calipers have ball bearings inside them, so be careful if you disassemble.  The calipers might pre-date the fork.

- https://velobase.com/ViewComponent.aspx?ID=662d6c01-095b-4ac5-9ea6-f0faa35f923c
- https://velobase.com/ViewComponent.aspx?ID=7414ed0b-f833-4ea9-baff-b358c6cb475d

Clearly its a threadded steerer, so you need to have a compatible quill stem if you want to be original, or a quill-threadless adapter for easier access to more modern stems.  Either's fine.

Congratulations on your build - please do post a photo when its all assembled.

Comment: Thank you for all the compliments and suggestions! I will leave the question open in case someone can find the right brand but I think you already did a great job and I will continue my research with this added knowledge. I will surely post the complete build when it's done!